# How can I use :not() without a page or post ID?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I wanted the CSS to apply to all the pages except for one, which is where the `:not()` comes in.

Now the problem is that the page I want to exclude is neither a page nor a post, so it does not have an ID I can use; it is a page created by a plugin, and the original "post" is actually a property (I use a property management plugin, so when I add a property, the plugin creates a single page for it visible on the website). I tried everything I could but could not find how to select this page, even though the inspect element shows it as `post-id-2114`.

Is there a way where I could use the URL to exclude it from the CSS? Or anything else that would work?

**CSS**

```
.single-property-image-thumb ***:not(.??)*** {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Please add relevant HTML and tell us which one item shouldn't be target by CSS.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. I'm a super beginner (still learning) I don't know how to provide the relevant HTML. would giving the link to the page I want to exclude help?

Comment: Add a page link, or HTML with `.single-property-image-thumb`s which can be styled and the one with could be excluded.

Comment: this is the link to the page i want to exclude https://cia-agency.co.uk/property/clifton-court-northwick-terrace-london-nw8/

Comment: Which `thumb` shouldn't be styled by styles in question?

Comment: ahh I don't want to apply the bottom margin to the image thumb of the page I linked (I need to style it differently). is that what you're asking? apologies I still find all of this confusing..

Answer (score 1):

Due to comments above, I try if I understand it well.

```
/* for all pages */
.single-property-image-thumb {
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

/* different styles for https://cia-agency.co.uk/property/clifton-court-northwick-terrace-london-nw8/
.postid-2114 is class on body element */
.postid-2114 .single-property-image-thumb {
    /* there will be styles just for linked page  */
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: omg it worked! i tried that exact same css before i asked here and it didnt work! thank you so much for your help and quick replies! much appreciated!

Comment: @fa2oush: maybe you forget space between `class`es, maybe cache... Glad to helped you.

Comment: A good thing to take away from @pavel's answer is that in CSS, you are often far better off applying general rules at a higher level and later indicating exceptions at a more detailed level, than you are tying yourself in :knots() with `:not()`. That's :not() to say that `:not()` isn't a very useful tool, but I do think that best practice is to use it sparingly.