# Choosing pages that CSS will work on for wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and elementor and some times i need css. Can anyone help me about how I can choose a specific page that css won't work on

I'm using elementor toogle. The toogle come as a closed by default but I want some page's toogle to be opened by default while other toogle, which I use in my website, stay closed by default.

For this purpose, I found the css that is below, but when I use that, all toogle in my website are open by default. For this, I want to except a specific page that the css won't work on.

```
.elementor-toggle .elementor-tab-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Many thaks for repliers

Comment: You need to find st. unique in pages where you want to show/hide it. Eg. id/class on body. There is no better answer without relevant HTML.

Comment: I gave similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566745/how-can-i-use-not-without-a-page-or-post-id/67567006#67567006 Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional tags, example in the header.php:

```
<?php if(is_page("page_id or slug")): ?>

    <style>
       /* some CSS */
    </style>
 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i wonder can i this transaction through theme css panel regarless of adding header.php?

Comment: directly in CSS you cannot use conditional tags, only in PHP, as in the example in header.php or through your functions.php